# Is it possible to see the macros of a compiled C program?

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to learn C and I have this C file that I want view the macros of. Is there a tool to view the macros of the compiled C file.

Comment: Do you mean the `#define` macros?

Comment: Yes, the ones that would typically go at the start of the document

Comment: @needhelpplease123 `view the macros` It is not clear if you want to see the macro definitions, or the macro expansions at the point where they are used.

Comment: I would want to see the macro definitions

Comment: @needhelpplease123 That's not possible since those are lost once the source code gets compiled, as explained in the posted answers. It's not always possible even if you have the full sources since some macros can be defined by the compiler and/or specified on the compiler command line.

Answer (score 2):

No. That's literally impossible.

The preprocessor is a textual replacement that happens before the main compile pass. There is no difference between using a macro and putting the code the macro expands to in its place.*

<sup>*Ignoring the debugger output. But even then you can do it if you know the right `#pragma` to tell it the file and line number.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

They're always defined in the header file(s) that you've imported with `#include`, or that those files in turn `#include`.

This may involve a lot of digging. It may involve going into files that make no sense to you because they're not written for casual inspection.

Any macros of any importance are usually documented. They may use other more complex implementation-specific macros that you shouldn't concern yourself with ordinarily, but if you're curious how they work the source is all there.

That being said, this is only relevant *if you have the source* and more specifically *a complete build environment*. Once compiled all these definitions, like the source itself, do not appear in the executable and cannot be inferred directly from the executable, especially not a release build.

> Unlike Java or C#, C compiles directly to machine code so there's no way to easily reverse that back to the source. There are "decompilers" that try, but they can only really guess as to the original source. VM-based languages like Java and C# only lightly compile the code, sot here are a lot of hints as to how that code was generated and reversing it is an easier process.